# Java - Multiple Boolean Conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I have this problem: I want to check if an int is bigger than 10, if not than if he is bigger then 100..and so on.
Is there a better way than just doing this:

```
 public void multipleIf(int x){
    if(x > 10){
        ...
    } else if(x > 100){
        ...
    } else if(...   
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: If it's not bigger than 10 check if it's bigger than 100. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number that is greater than 100 is always greater than 10.

If you want only numbers in the range 10-100 exclusive, you can use operators. You could test for a number that is greater than 10 but less than 100 by using logical operators:

```
if(x > 10 && x < 100) {
    /* Body */
} else if(x > 100 && x < ....) {
    /* Body */
}
```

The `&&` is a logical AND operator that checks if both conditions are true. So, it checks if `x` is inside the range, exclusive.

If you want only numbers greater than 100, use separate `if` statements.

You can also use a switch statement.

Comment: Thanks I didin't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you know what your limit is (say 10,000), you can simply start from the top.

```
if(x > 10000)
    ....statement 1
else if (x > 1000) // using this else here is important
    ....statement 2
else if (x > 100)
    ....statement 3
else if (x > 10)
    ....statement 4
```

The `else` is important because it only executes if the previous `if` (or `else if`) is not executed (the statement is false). Thus we can see that statement 1 executes for any `x` greater than 10,000. If it's not greater than 10,000, but greater than 1000, then statement 2 executes. If `x` is not greater than 1,000, but greater than 100, then statement 3 executes. And at the end, depending on your code, you can just put an `else` statement somewhere.